# dos2unix doesn't convert the env file even with -f option

Tags: dos2unix

When I ran the the npm command, it threw an error like this.

```
10:13 $ npm install --legacy-peer-deps

> project-client@1.0.0 prepare
> scripts/transpile

/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory
```

I figured that it had something to do with a line ending issue in Windows, so I tried the following.

```
✔ /usr/bin
11:00 $ dos2unix env
dos2unix: Failed to open temporary output file: Permission denied
dos2unix: problems converting file env
✘-13 /usr/bin
11:01 $ sudo dos2unix env
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x02 found at line 1
dos2unix: Skipping binary file env
```

The answer on the post below says that adding the option `-f` will force the conversion,

[dos2unix: Binary symbol found, skipping binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763687/dos2unix-binary-symbol-found-skipping-binary-file)

but it still didn't let me convert it.

```
✔ /usr/bin
11:01 $ sudo dos2unix env -f
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x02 found at line 1
dos2unix: Skipping binary file env
```

Is there any work around to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option -f, then the file name:

```
sudo dos2unix -f env
```